# Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Stopped Working when adding connection

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

On the next screen when I click on Test Connection everything is fine. I get a successful connection. When I click on ok my Visual Studio crash without warning. What is wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your database name if it is working correctly  or check  your database installation to connect to any stdio because other input data is seeing correctly.

Comment: All is correct. Do you know if it exist other tools than can connect to SQL Server to test the connection?

Comment: your connection is ok, you should find problem in other workspace, like cpu performance , install db ...

Comment: some of installation or any operating system fault are here.You may  look at these sign.